# Making it harder to accidentally delete a file in Linux

Tags: linux, synology

I have a synology NAS server which runs linux. I use it to back up files. I want to make it very difficult for someone to accidentally delete files. The permission model is just read / write. I need to grant write access so that users can back up files. But, I'd like to have something like when they tried to delete a file they had to enter a password or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Use alias rm="rm -i", this will prompt the user before deleting the file.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I am not familiar with Synology products, so I can only answer about Linux in general.*

What you are asking is not generally possible; on a Linux system having creation/write access implies also having deletion capabilities - there is no separate permission bit for deletion. More specifically:

- Having write access to a directory means that you can create and delete files regardless of the permissions to the files themselves.
- Having write access to a file means that you can modify its contents, including truncating it to zero length, but not that you can completely delete the file itself.

In general, backup applications need full recursive write access to the destination directory where they perform their backups. So, I would expect any user that can *store* files on your device to be able to delete them as well.

If you want your users to store files without being able to delete them easily, such functionality would generally have to be implemented into whatever server process your device uses to provide remote access to its filesystem. A potential approach could be for the server process to automatically remove the write permission from files and directories after they are backed up so that the user has to reset it before deletion, thus providing a layer of protection against accidental deletion.

Another, potentially more powerful, approach would be to have the server `chown` the files to a different user after creation, thus requiring someone to login as a different account before deleting them. That could imply using a different password, without having to jump through hoops the various remote access protocols were not designed for.

If you cannot get the server process to provide this functionality, you might be able to achieve something similar with a `cron` job that changes the ownership and permissions in the backup directory e.g. every hour or so. Alternatively, if you have shell access you could write a shell-based daemon that uses `inotify` to act as soon as a file is created.

On a sidenote, if your device is using an `ext3` or `ext4` filesystem for its disks, you might want to consider using `chattr +a` for your backup directories - that allows files to be created but not deleted for as long as the append-only (`a`) flag is set. In addition, `chattr +i` will make the target file immutable, preventing deletion and/or modification. The restrictions imposed by using `chattr` are binding for all users, including the `root` user.

Answer (score 1):

If they've got full shell access it's not straightforward. You could write a shell script called 'rm' which did something different, and put it in the user `PATH` before `/bin`. It would intercept any attempts to run 'rm' without an explicit path. That may cause issues if any scripts need to be run by the user which genuinely need the rm command. Or you could write a shell function to do something similar, that would also take precedence.

Comment: couldn't it also be easily over ridden by using `\rm` ?

Comment: `\rm` would still call the first instance of `rm` in the shell's path (at least in bash). `/bin/rm` would still work, so it's no use for anyone who knows what they're doing.

Comment: is there a way of making sure the path can't be modified then?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option would be

```
alias rm='rm -iv'
```

It would ask user to press `'y'<ENTER>` to confirm. It can be overridden/bypassed with `\rm` or `rm -f` in place of `rm` at command line.
This should be usually enough to prevent such accidents.

---

If you want to force user to confirm with something else, say a string `YES` in uppercase, you can create a function named `rm`

```
function rm(){
    local REPLY
    echo you are about to execute rm command with below arguments: >&2
    echo "$@" >&2
    read -p "Enter YES to continue" REPLY
    [ "$REPLY" == "YES" ] && /bin/rm -v "$@"
}
```

This is not affected if the user changes PATH variable.
This can be overridden/bypassed by using `command rm` or `/bin/rm` in place of `rm` at command line.